# adding animation when showing a div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate, show

,
HI,

I have a div that i create on the fly witch is dispalyed none, in the first place, then i want to show it using jquery .show(), but also have a .animate() when it shows.

Did this:

`$(newDiv).show().animate({
        width: "270px",
        borderColor: "#4a4a4a"
        },800);`

But it didnt like it (firefox), it says this error:

```
Error: attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
```

How can i make this work? by the way on chrome it works fine...

By the way this works:

`$(newDiv).show('slow', { animation: 'slide' })`

But i need to have my animation function.

Thank in advance.

Comment: @viswanathan that's for `.css()` not for `.animate()`

Comment: @Ovi - it's likely something else in your code, can you post a link?

Comment: @AlienWebguy , thank you, but i cant post a link cuz i am working on a project locally. ill see if i can figure something out with this problem...

Comment: @AlienWebguy, i am also geeting this Error: a.ownerDocument is null, could it be conected? and again this is only FF.

Comment: Ok shot in the dark here, what version of JQuery are you using? That was an old bug in 1.3 if I recall. Can you recreate the bug on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

for me it works fine , here is the example [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/gArhp/)

Comment: I dont know it keeps on giving me that error i wrote... i am using this in side a iframe and after the error it reloads in the iframe the hole parent document...